# Trying to get yum to install dependencies from own repo

Tags: repository, yum

I have created a yum repository on a machine I have. I have thrown certain RPM's into it and created the repo. On my second machine I am able to view these repos and the files in them by doing a yum list. The second part of this is I have done a spec file that creates an rpm that depends on all of the RPM's in this specific repo but when I do a yum install createdrpm it determines the correct dependencies, but does not install them from my own repo.

I have tried searching over the web for this, but no luck unfortunately. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `rpm` `spec` file, the `Requires` section should list the package names that are shown in the yum repo, not the rpm filenames.

For example:

```
 yum list | grep something
 something.noarch v1.0
```

The `rpm` `spec` file should have:

```
Require: something >= 1.0
```